# Send and receive files from FTP in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, ftps

I'm new to Spring Framework and, indeed, I'm learning and using **Spring Boot**. Recently, in the app I'm developing, I made Quartz Scheduler work, and now I want to make Spring Integration work there: FTP connection to a server to write and read files from.

What I want is really simple (as I've been able to do so in a previous java application). I've got two Quartz Jobs scheduled to fired in different times daily: one of them reads a file from a FTP server and another one writes a file to a FTP server.

I'll detail what I've developed so far.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:ws-config.xml")
@EnableIntegration
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private Configuration configuration;

    //...

    @Bean
    public DefaultFtpsSessionFactory  myFtpsSessionFactory(){
        DefaultFtpsSessionFactory sess = new DefaultFtpsSessionFactory();
        Ftp ftp = configuration.getFtp();
        sess.setHost(ftp.getServer());
        sess.setPort(ftp.getPort());
        sess.setUsername(ftp.getUsername());
        sess.setPassword(ftp.getPassword());
        return sess;
    }

}
```

The following class I've named it as a FtpGateway, as follows:

```
@Component
public class FtpGateway {

    @Autowired
    private DefaultFtpsSessionFactory sess;

    public void sendFile(){
        // todo
    }

    public void readFile(){
        // todo
    }

}
```

I'm reading [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html) documentation to learn to do so. Spring Integration's FTP seems to be event driven, so I don't know how can I execute either of the sendFile() and readFile() from by Jobs when the trigger is fired at an exact time.

The documentation tells me [something](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-intro) about using Inbound Channel Adapter (to read files from a FTP?), Outbound Channel Adapter (to write files to a FTP?) and Outbound Gateway (to do what?):

> Spring Integration supports sending and receiving files over FTP/FTPS by providing three client side endpoints: Inbound Channel Adapter, Outbound Channel Adapter, and Outbound Gateway. It also provides convenient namespace-based configuration options for defining these client components.

So, I haven't got it clear as how to follow.

Please, could anybody give me a hint?

Thank you!

**EDIT**:

Thank you @M. Deinum. First, I'll try a simple task: read a file from the FTP, the poller will run every 5 seconds. This is what I've added:

```
@Bean
public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(myFtpsSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/Entrada");
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv"));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}


@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(inbound);
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File(configuracion.getDirFicherosDescargados()));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    return source;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            Object payload = message.getPayload();
            if(payload instanceof File){
                File f = (File) payload;
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            }else{
                System.out.println(message.getPayload());
            }
        }

    };
}
```

Then, when the app is running, I put a new csv file intro "Entrada" remote folder, but the handler() method isn't run after 5 seconds... I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Configure and in and outbound channel, attach a poller and spring integration should do all you now do manually.

Comment: I'm not able to make it work. Please, could you provide any site where explains how to do it, @M.Deinum?

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging to watch the poll events.

Comment: I don't see that you use `ftpInboundFileSynchronizer()` from the `ftpMessageSource()`. There is some suspicious `inbound`, but we have no idea what is that about...

Comment: @russellhoff i'm stuck at the same point.. Did it work for you?

Comment: @Manisha yes it did. I'll update my post.

Comment: How did you transferred the files from local to the remote FTP using outbound adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Please add **@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)** over your poller method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **SPRING BATCH** with tasklet. It is far easier to configure bean, crone time, input source with existing interfaces provided by Spring.

https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-spring-batch

Above example is annotation and xml based both, you can use either.

**Other benefit** Take use of listeners and parallel steps. This framework can be used in Reader - Processor - Writer manner as well.